# Struggling with WPF internal methods

Tags: c#, wpf

UPDATE: So, I have a solution to my immediate problem. I haven't succeeded in making "my own" `TreeView` class. But, the reason I wanted to do that was because controls based on `ButtonBase` don't function in a `Popup` from a `TreeView`, and with the help of @MarkFeldman, I have found a solution that comes at it from a different angle.

The problem is that the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events bubble, and that bubbling crosses the logical tree boundary between the `Popup` and its owner. So, when you click on something hosted inside the `Popup`, the `TreeViewItem` and `TreeView` that ultimately own the `Popup` get to hear about it. This then triggers code inside the `TreeView` that checks, "Do I have focus?", and if not, *helpfully* sets focus back to itself -- but being a separate logical tree, the `Popup` has its own focus context, and so this effectively *steals* focus from the `Button` control while it is in the middle of processing a click. The `Button` responds to this by ignoring the click.

This erroneous handling in the `TreeView` only happens when `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events reach it. What if there were a way to prevent it from seeing those events in the first place? Well, if you intercept the `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` events and mark them `Handled`, then the framework *doesn't generate* `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events to begin with.

Looking at the Reference Source, it looks like `ButtonBase`'s click handling is tied up in a couple of `protected` methods:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,414
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,478

This means you can call them from your own subclasses! So, instead of making "my own" `TreeView` where all controls behave properly, instead I can make "my own" `CheckBox` that works properly in a `Popup` from a `TreeView`. Since all of the actual click handling is directly accessible, and the events it *normally* responds to use the same `EventArgs` type as the `Preview` events, and on top of it the default handling takes care of marking the events as `Handled`, the entire implementation boils down to this:

```
public class CheckBoxThatWorks : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) => base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) => base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
}
```

Nice!

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I need to make a clone of the `TreeView` WPF class -- a copy of the control that runs out of my own code. (There is a bug in the control and Microsoft doesn't seem to deem it high-enough priority to fix, and it makes it completely impossible to host buttons (including check boxes and radio buttons) within pop-ups shown from `TreeViewItem`s. [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190202/button-controls-hosted-in-popup-windows-do-not-wor.html#reply-form))

I am running into serious difficulties with the amount of `internal` shenanigans Microsoft has undertaken in the implementation of base WPF controls. A couple of issues I've bumped into:

- Controls have a property `HandlesScrolling` that allows them to take over basic scrolling handling from `ScrollViewer`. But, it's marked `internal`, making it seemingly impossible for me to have a control of my own that does its own handling of scrolling from keyboard input. I was going to try having my `TreeView` handle keyboard scrolling in `OnPreviewKeyDown` instead of `OnKeyDown`, so that it can prevent `KeyDown` events from being raised for the keys it intercepts. I haven't gotten far enough to know what caveats there might be about this.
- The Visual States system allows you to declare what styles should be applied when different states are entered, but actually entering states seems to be tied up in the virtual method `ChangeVisualState` on the `Control` type. All controls that want to switch between visual states can override this method and inspect their state to determine which Visual State should be shown. Oh wait. They can't because the method is `internal`! Apparently only Microsoft gets to create controls that set their own visual states??

Are there any strategies I can use to work around these limitations, or am I just completely out of luck?

Comment: in regards to the internal methods You could either copy the internal code, or use reflection to invoke it

Comment: The internal code is in a base class that is core to the framework. I'm wanting to make my own `TreeView`, and a `TreeView` is an `ItemsControl`, and `ItemsControl` is defined in `PresentationFramework` and has `internal` methods that, being `internal`, can normally only be accessed by other code within `PresentationFramework`.

Comment: In your original problem is it just buttons you have to worry about in your popup? Because if so then the simple solution is to just intercept the button's bubbling mouse event on its way up. The reason they're not working is because popups are part of the visual tree and the TreeViewItems block the tunneling message from going back down. This doesn't really seem like a bug to me so much as designed behavior that can be easily overridden.

Comment: Instead of using Popup use `ContextMenu`, I just checked your problem and resolved it by using `ContextMenu` instead of `Popup`. Why would you use `Popup` instead of `ContextMenu`? And also I didn't use a Custom `UC`.

Comment: @MarkFeldman From my investigation, what's actually going on is that the `TreeView` control contains code that aims to work around a particular bit of UI clunky-ness that can occur when focus gets moved outside of a `TreeView`. When it gets a click event, it tries to heuristically set focus back to itself, guessing which item container should have focus, or just setting it to the `TreeView` if it can't figure out which container. When you put a `Button` into a `TreeViewItem`, this click event fires and says, "Oh, I _do_ have focus, I guess I don't have to do anything. But, ...

Comment: ...the problem arises when you put a `Button` into a `Popup` inside a `TreeViewItem`, because the `Popup` is its own logical root, so the `TreeView` handler's code for checking "Is the focus still effectively within me?" thinks that it doesn't have logical focus any more. But it _does_ have logical focus, because the `Popup` has focus and the `TreeViewItem` owns the `Popup`. I used a detour library to replace the implementation of the click handler with one that contains extra code to traverse the boundary from the `Popup`'s logical root across to its true owner, and this implementation ...

Comment: ...did resolve the issue. I'm fairly confident that if Microsoft simply copy/pasted my code, it would resolve my issue. My confidence is not so high, maybe 75%? that my changes wouldn't cause unexpected unrelated problems. :-)

Comment: @XAMIMAX Well, a `ContextMenu` is for picking an option from a suite of selections. Its expected lifetime is one click; once you've selected your item, the `ContextMenu` knows what it needs to know. A `Popup`, on the other hand, is for displaying a view with a longer lifespan. It's still temporary, but it sticks around until something closes it, such as a button click or losing focus. My `Popup` contains a dynamically-built array of `CheckBox` controls. A user might want to pop it up, and then check off multiple controls before dismissing it. My problem arises because a `CheckBox` is really...

Comment: ... a `ToggleButton` is really a `Button`, so this behaviour that blocks clicks going to `Button` objects also blocks clicks going to `CheckBox`es.

Comment: I just made a test app and gave a `TreeViewItem` a `ContextMenu` with a bunch of `CheckBox` controls in it, and the behaviour of the `CheckBox` controls was in fact as desired! But, the visual appearance was _really weird_ :-) I guess I'll spend some time tomorrow to see if I can re-style a `ContextMenu` to look like a `Popup`...

Comment: I knocked up a quick test and simply gave each button a PreviewMouseDown handler which set the args `Handled` property to true (so it didn't bubble up to the TreeView) and then checked/toggled the button state explicitly. I'd like to see a more generic solution to this, but in a pinch it gets the job done.

Comment: Also I can see why ContextMenu would have worked, unlike Popups they're not part of their associated object's visual tree, so their messages won't bubble/tunnel through to the TreeView. If the visual effect is wrong then you should be able to fix that by substituting the ControlTemplate? The main issue with doing this is that your bindings will all break as well, but that's easily fixed by binding via [a proxy](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: I will experiment with these approaches. Thanks very much for all the input!

Comment: I have boiled it down to this, which seems to resolve the issue: Create a `CheckBox` subclass that processes its `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` events _as though they were_ not preview events. I am going to update the question to reflect this, since it isn't possible to format code nicely in a comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Someone has voted to close this question on the grounds that the original question is too broad. I disagree that it is too broad, because the original question was _specifically_ asking, "Are there any strategies available for working with frameworks that have `internal` members you need to implement or override?" Just because the question was obviated by taking a different approach to the root cause doesn't mean that the question itself was invalid. That said, a) I no longer have immediate need for that question answered, and b) the answer might very well be "You are out of luck" anyway. :-P

Comment: If you find a solution to your question, you should post it as an answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Comment: I agree @TylerH. The thing is, I _didn't_ find a solution to my question. I just side-stepped it completely. The update I posted is _not_ an answer to the question, and won't help anybody who finds this question and is also struggling with `internal` methods in would-be .NET Framework base classes. That's why I didn't make it an answer.

Comment: @JonathanGilbert You found a workaround; a lot of people would call that a solution. You don't have to accept it as the answer that solves the original problem as asked, fo course.